# invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' error

Tags: python, function, loops, python-3.x, radix

I just started coding about 5 weeks ago and I am working on a code for my game development class and I'm just terribly stuck on an issue. When I run my code, I get the "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''" error and I'm unsure of what I'm doing wrong. I'll post my code below. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

```
start = 0
def addition(num1):
    return num1 + num1

def square(num):
    print("I'm in square")
    return num * num

def display(message):
    """Display game instuctions"""
    print(message)
def instructions():
    """Display game instuctions"""
    print("Welcome to the world's greatest game")


def main():
    instructions()
    scores = [("Roger", 3456), ("Justin", 2320), ("Beth", 1422)]

    start = input("Would you like to view the high score options? y/n ")
    if start == "y":
        print("""\
        Hello! Welcome to the high scores!
        Here are the current high score leaders!:
        """)
        print(scores)
        print("""\n\
        0 - Sort high scores
        1 - Add high score
        2 - Reverse the order
        3 - Remove a score
        4 - Square a number
        5 - Add 2 numbers together
        """)
        option = int(input())
        while option < 6:
            start = int(input("Please enter your selection")) 
            print(scores)
            if option == 0:
                scores.sort()
                print("These are the scores sorted alphabetically")
                print(scores)
            if option == 1:
                print(scores)
                print("Please enter your name and score; After entering your name, hit the return key and enter your score")
                name = input()
                score = int(input())
                entry = (name,score)
                scores.append(entry)
                print(scores)
            if option == 2:
                print(scores)
                scores.reverse()
                print("\nHere are the scores reversed")
                print(scores)
            if option == 3:
                print(scores)
                print("Please enter the high score you would like to remove. After typing the name, hit the return key and enter the score")
                name1 = input()
                score1 = int(input())
                remove = (name1,score1)
                scores.remove(remove)
                print(scores)
            if option == 4:
                val = int(input("Give me a number to square"))
                sqd = square(val)
                print(sqd)
            if option == 5:
                val0 = int(input("Give me one number"))
                val1 = int(input("Give me another number"))
                addi = (val0 + val1)
                print(addi)

main()
```

Comment: You must enter string value and try to convert string to int. Which line you got exception and what is user input to that staement?

Comment: You are trying to converting an empty string to `int`. Check your `input` calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely happening in your code since you ask the user for input twice at the beginning of the loop.

```
...
option = int(input())
while option < 6:
  start = int(input("Please enter your selection")) 
...
```

This also means whatever they enter first (in the empty prompt, which is maybe where you are entering an empty string by acident) will always be the option (i.e. your `start` variable is never used to determine which option to pick). Perhaps just keep one variable (say, `option`) and change your code to be something like:

```
option = int(input("Please enter your selection"))
while option < 6
  ...
  option = option = int(input("Please enter your selection"))
```

If you want to show some sort of error and exit the program when they enter a non-int, you can use a `try-except` block:

```
...
try:
  option = int(input("Please enter your selection")) 
  while option < 6:  
    ...
    option = int(input("Please enter your selection")) 
except ValueError:
  print("Error!")
```

Comment: Is `option = option = int(input("Please enter your selection"))` any different from `option = int(input("Please enter your selection"))`?

Answer (score 1):

1. You enter string value and try to convert string to int.

e.g.

```
>>> int(raw_input())
e
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'e'
>>>
```

2. Use `if - elif`

e.g.

```
if option == 0:
    # Do coding for option 0
elif option==1:
    # Do coding for option 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening when your input is not a number, thus `int()` will fail.

For example:

```
>>> int(input())
hey
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hey'
```

To fix this, you can continually ask for an input until it is an `int`, through a `try/except` clause along with a loop.